# Why is this multithreaded counter producing the right result?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning multithreaded counter and I'm wondering why no matter how many times I ran the code it produces the right result.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            CounterThread thread = new CounterThread(counter);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}

public class CounterThread extends Thread {
    private Counter counter;
    public CounterThread(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.counter.add();
        }
        this.counter.print();
    }
}

public class Counter {
    private int count = 0;
    public void add() {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.count);
    }
}
```

And this is the result

```
10
20
30
```

Not sure if this is just a fluke or is this expected? I thought the result is going to be

```
10
10
10
```

Comment: Try with counting up to a million. Or ten million.

Comment: I think you need to try with bigger values. It could be that the first thread has finished before the second thread is completely initialized and ready to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try increasing the loop count from 10 to 10000 and you'll likely see some differences in the output.

The most logical explanation is that with only 10 additions, a thread is too fast to finish before the next thread gets started and adds on top of the previous result.

Comment: Thanks. That was it!.

Comment: And the moral of the story is this -- even if your code appears to work every time you try it, that doesn't mean you don't have a race condition. Race conditions cannot be reliably detected by just running the code.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning multithreaded counter and I'm wondering why no matter how many times I ran the code it produces the right result.

<ttdr> Check out @manouti's answer. </ttdr>

Even though you are sharing the same `Counter` object, which is unsynchronized, there are a couple of things that are causing your 3 threads to run (or look like they are running) serially with data synchronization.  I had to work hard on my 8 proc Intel Linux box to get it to show any interleaving.

- When threads start and when they finish, there are memory barriers that are crossed.  According to the Java Memory Model, the guarantee is that the thread that does the `thread.join()` will see the results of the thread published to it but I suspect a central memory flush happens when the thread finishes.  This means that if the threads run serially (and with such a small loop it's hard for them *not* to) they will act as if there is no concurrency because they will see each other's changes to the `Counter`.
- Putting a `Thread.sleep(100);` at the front of the thread `run()` method causes it to not run serially.  It also hopefully causes the threads to cache the `Counter` and not see the results published by other threads that have already finished.  Still needed help though.
- Starting the threads in a loop after they all have been instantiated helps concurrency.
- Another thing that causes synchronization is:

  ```
  System.out.println(this.count);
  ```

  `System.out` is a `Printstream` which is a synchronized class.  Every time a thread calls `println(...)` it is publishing its results to central memory.  If you instead recorded the value and then displayed it later, it might show better interleaving.
- I really wonder if some [Java compiler inlining](https://techblug.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/java-jit-compiler-inlining/) of the `Counter` class at some point is causing part of the artificial synchronization.  For example, I'm really surprised that a `Thread.sleep(1000)` at the front and end of the `thread.run()` method doesn't show 10,10,10.
- It should be noted that on a non-intel architecture, with different memory and/or thread models, this might be easier to reproduce.
- Oh, as commentary and apropos of nothing, typically it is recommended to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.

So the following is my tweaks to your test program.

```
public class CounterThread extends Thread {
    private Counter counter;
    int result;
    ...
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // good pattern
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            counter.add();
        }
        result = counter.count;
        // no print here
    }
}
```

Then your main could do something like:

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
List<CounterThread> counterThreads = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    counterThread.add(new CounterThread(counter));
}
// start in a loop after constructing them all which improves the overlap chances
for (CounterThread counterThread : counterThreads) {
    counterThread.start();
}
// wait for them to finish
for (CounterThread counterThread : counterThreads) {
    counterThread.join();
}
// print the results
for (CounterThread counterThread : counterThreads) {
    System.out.println(counterThread.result);
}
```

Even with this, I never see 10,10,10 output on my box and I often see 10,20,30.  Closest I get is 12,12,12.

Shows you how hard it is to properly test a threaded program.  Believe me, if this code was in production and you were *expecting* the "free" synchronization is when it would fail you.  ;-)